# What is `[submodule "(heads/master)"]` in `.gitmodules`?

Tags: git, git-submodules

In one of my projects I have a "strange" entry in my `.gitmodules`:

```
...
[submodule "tools"]
    path = tools
    url = https://...
[submodule "(heads/master)"]
    branch = master
```

Questions:

- What is the entry `submodule "(heads/master)"`?
- Did I add it with some command?
- Can/Should I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a submodule called (heads/master). You probably added the submodule using something like this... `git submodule add (heads/master)`. To remove the submodule `git submodule deinit -f (heads/master)`.

Comment: The command `git submodule add "(heads/master)"` returns "repo URL: '(heads/master)' must be absolute or begin with ./|../". So it doesn't work that way.

Comment: `.gitmodules` defines the path. You may need to add quotes around the path if you have parens. Also you want to call `deinit` and not `add`

Comment: After intensive investigation in my bash history, I finally found the command that created that entry. A incorrect combination of `git submodule`, `cut` and `git config`. There were never a submodule with this name, so I just removed the offending lines from `.gitmodules`. Anyway thanks, as your answer made clear that this is my fault and not some Git feature.